# How to create a subdirectory when user posts an article?

Tags: php, html

I want to understand the mechanism of a system which is described below:
When a user posts an article on my site, it should create a sub-directory to store the article data in it.

For example: site http://www.scoopwhoop.com/
It is a blog and if you link on any one of the article, the link would be like:
http://www.scoopwhoop.com/news/stephen-hawking-speech-software-online/

If you see there isn't any .html or .php in the link? 
How can I do that?? My site is based on PHP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It are no 'real' subdirectories, but rewrites. For example, the .htaccess catches the url (like, /user/jan/), and redirect it to a php file like this: 
index.php?page=/user/jan/'.

See [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) link for more detailed information.

Answer (score 2):

Its mod rewrite. Read about it. Its just hidden redirection for specific file.
All link its redirected for example to one and only one: index.php file. That file parse whole url and run specific action. You can set mod rewrite formula inside htaccess file. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^download-([^-]+)$ download.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Any link, like download-test will execute download.php?id=test

Comment: If possible can I have a tutorial link so I can understand it in a better way?

Comment: one from first results (google), but seems to be good for beginners:
http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/